# How does the Lumber Mill work?

Tags: black-and-white-2

My questions are about Lumber Mill:

- If you make more people refiners. The efficiency gets higher or it just takes less time?
- Do I need to put wood on Lumber Mill or they just take it automatically?
- Do they put the "converted" wood in first best Storage or just leave it next to the building?

Comment: Don't worry about people confusing this with Pokemon Black 2/White 2. Our tagging system should do more than enough in differentiating the two.

Answer (score 2):

The various refining facilities are pretty cool in that as long as they have one refiner working them (doesnt even have to be a deciple, simply having a house nearby makes people work there anyway!) they will refine the resources.

From what I've been able to tell from playing the game, the number of refiners slightly improves the rate at which resources are refined, but the building only supports eight at a time!

You cannot place resources onto a refinery unfortunately, so make sure you place them as close to the storehouses as possible, as the villagers have to walk to the storehouse, take the resource, return it to the mill, refine it, then take it back to the store again, so building them close by does both you and them favours.

And, as mentioned before, they do take it back to the storehouse.